# Control for dimming lights with programming language

Tags: light, philips-hue

I'm planning on showing my sound work for a show, I'm just wondering if it's possible to control the lights getting darker and brighter slowly?
It starts from the pitch black at the beginning, and getting brighter and darker, and it turned back to pitch black at the end of sound.
I have no experiences about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Hue API to [change the state of a light](https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api/lights-api/#set-light-state) or [of a group of lights](https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api/groupds-api/#set-gr-state) (links require you create a free Hue developer account to access), you can set a `transitiontime` property. This will cause the light to smoothly transition from its current state to the chosen state over that time period. This way you'd only need to send commands to the lights when you want them to start a new transition.

Note however that you will have trouble doing a transition from complete darkness: the lowest brightness for Hue bulbs is nowhere near pitch black, so you'd notice the jump from "off" to "brightness 1".

There is also a second [Entertainment API](https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-entertainment/philips-hue-entertainment-api/) that supports streaming light changes (i.e. up to about 10 times a second) rather than relying on transitions. This is somewhat more involved though.